# Error Code 429: Active X Component Cannot Create Object

Tags: visual-c++, com, excel, vba

I have a .Net Class Library which I refer in VBA and all goes well. When I try to use the same Excel file on some other machine the error is: `Error Code 429:Active X component Cannot create Object`

The error is recd for line

```
set a = createobject("dllname.classname")
```

However I am registering the DLL at runtime and it gives no error for the line

```
Dim a as dllname.classname
```

This error happens on my Win-7 pc where as works just fine on Win-XP PC. Please help because I need to run my application using the Excel Sheet.

Comment: The "registering at runtime" angle is an unlikely one, given that an application normally doesn't have write access to the registry keys.  Register with an installer.  And use "classname", not "classsname".

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/build-and-deploy-a-.net-com-assembly/) has a good writeup on ensuring your assembly is late-bindable, i.e. via `createobject()`.

Takeaways:

- Make sure your assembly includes a ProgID attribute
- Use `regasm` on the target (deployment) machine to do the actual registration of the COM class